# Proof of a theorem on measurable functions

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose $(\Omega, \mathscr{L})$ and $(S, \mathscr{B})$ are measure spaces and that a collection of sets $\mathscr{A}$ generates $\mathscr{B}$, i.e., $\sigma(\mathscr{A}) = \mathscr{B}$. Let $X: \Omega \rightarrow S$. If $X^{-1}(A) \in \mathscr{L} \quad \forall \space A \in \mathscr{A}$, then $X$ is measurable $\mathscr{B}$ (or $X$ is a random variable).

Comment: Thanks for taking our remarks on your previous question into account.

Comment: @justt I am sorry for that behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\mathcal M = \{B\in \mathscr B : X^{-1}(B) \in \mathscr L\}$. You want to show that $\mathcal M$ is a monotone class and use the [monotone class theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_class_theorem), which states that if $M(\mathscr A)$is the smallest monotone class containing the algebra $\mathscr A$, then $M(\mathscr A) = \sigma(\mathscr A) = \mathscr B$. Now since by hypothesis $\mathcal M$ contains $\mathscr A$, and itself is a monotone class, then $\mathcal M$ contains $M(\mathscr A) = \mathscr B$. So $\mathcal M = \mathscr B$ which is exactly saying that $X$ is measurable.

Comment: One side of the monotone class theorem (the easyest side) is allready enough.

Comment: The answer of @drhab is way simpler, the monotone class theorem is best suited for situations where it is hard to show that some collection is a sigma-algebra.

Comment: Is there any other way to prove that $\mathcal M$ is a sigma algebra other than proving it as monotone class.

Comment: Yes, just use the definition and show that $\mathcal M$ is stable by countable union and finite intersection !

Comment: Please check if my approach is correct.  
$B_1, B_2, ... \in \mathcal M \Longrightarrow X^{-1}(B_i) \in \mathscr{L}$. Then for $\bigcup\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} X^{-1}(B_i) \Longrightarrow  X^{-1}(\bigcup\limits_{i=0}^{\infty}B_i)$

Comment: Indeed $\bigcup\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} X^{-1}(B_i) = X^{-1}(\bigcup\limits_{i=0}^{\infty}B_i)$. Proof :  $x$ is in the first set iff there exists $i$ such that $x\in X^{-1}(B_i)$, iff there exists $i$ such that $X(x)\in B_i$, iff $X(x)\in \bigcup\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} B_i$ iff $x  \in  X^{-1}(\bigcup\limits_{i=0}^{\infty}B_i)$, iff $x$ is in the second set.

Comment: Thanks a lot! you are justt great :)

Comment: @sv_jan5 These comments illustrate that preimages are indeed coöperative (as I mentioned in my answer). You find similar results for intersections and complements.

Comment: @drhab Yeah, I couldn't understand that term in your answer. Can you give some references (book or lecture notes) where I can see more of such examples? I still don't feel confident about this concept.

Comment: @sv_jan5 It all boils down to the properties $f^{-1}(\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i) = \bigcup_{i\in I} f^{-1}(A_i)$, and $f^{-1}(\bigcap_{i\in I} A_i) = \bigcap_{i\in I} f^{-1}(A_i)$, for any arbitrary (finite, countable, even uncountable) index set $I$. Same proof as before ! Remark that replacing preimages by images in the intersection property doesn't work : $f(A\cap B)$ might be smaller than $f(A) \cap f(B)$. That's why drhab highlighted that preimages are cooperative. Images are not !

Comment: Exactly as @justt says. Also $f^{-1}(A^c)=f^{-1}(A)^c$ deserves to be mentioned.

Comment: @drhab Can you help me to prove the property which you mentioned. $x \in f^{-1}(A^c) \Leftrightarrow f(x) \in A^c \Leftrightarrow f(x) \in \Omega - A $ Can you complete the proof?

Comment: $\dots\iff f(x)\notin A\iff x\notin f^{-1}(A)\iff x\in f^{-1}(A)^c$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got it now.

Answer (score 8):

The collection of subsets of $S$ that have a preimage under $X$ in $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal L$ can be shown to be a $\sigma$-algebra.

This is not really difficult to prove, since preimages are very coöperative in this.

So if this collection contains $\mathcal A$ as a subcollection then it will also contain $\mathcal B=\mathcal\sigma(\mathcal A)$ as a subcollection.

That means exactly that $X$ is measurable.